# Equivalent of javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement in Simple XML Serialization Framework

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

Does [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) have an equivalent annotation type of [javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html) or [XmlAnyAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyAttribute.html)?

Comment: Take a look at @ElementUnion, if this does not suit then you can try write a Converter..

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I did look at @ElementUnion before asking this question.  My impression is that it is different from XmlAnyElement which is exactly what its name indicates - any xml element. It is a collection of xml elements that do not match other annotated fields.

Comment: Converter looks like the way to go for these things.

Comment: I tried to implement a converter, but got the following error: The type org.simpleframework.xml.core.Converter is not visible.